# Ошибка Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, syntax

Пишет, что ошибка во второй строке

```
age = int(input("Сколько тебе лет? ")
weight = int(input("Сколько ты весишь килограммов? "))
moon_weight = weight / 6
print("\nЗнаете ли вы, что на луне вы бы весили всего", moon_weight, "кг?")
  sun_weight = weight * 27.1
print("А вот находясь на Солнце, вы бы весили", sun_weight, "кг")
input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти")
```

Comment: В первой - не хватает закрывающей скобки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первой строке скобка не закрыта. И проверь пятую строку, там ненужные отступы, которые приведут к ошибке. Ниже исправленный вариант

```
age = int(input("Сколько тебе лет? "))
weight = int(input("Сколько ты весишь килограммов? "))
moon_weight = weight / 6
print("\nЗнаете ли вы, что на луне вы бы весили всего", moon_weight, "кг?")
sun_weight = weight * 27.1
print("А вот находясь на Солнце, вы бы весили", sun_weight, "кг")
input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Просто писало, что ошибка во второй строке, это меня с толку сбило